# ixmlserialize.readxml not called if first element is empty

Tags: c#, xml

I have xml file. If first element is empty ixmlserializable.readxml not called and I can't deserialize element . But if first element has data ixmlserializable.readxml has called. How should I deserialize element

content of xml file:

```
<IncomeType>
          <PersonBasic xsi:nil="true" />
          <IncomeTypeFrom>
            <ID>2</ID>
            <Name>Business</Name>
            <IsSystem>False</IsSystem>
          </IncomeTypeFrom>
        </IncomeType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no data, then `null` for that property would actually be accurate. There is *nothing to deserialize.*